# Cannot Resolve symbol 'R' in Android Studio :"manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I'm a beginner and I use Android Studio. A problem keeps on bothers me.

It keeps on showing "Cannot Resolve symbol 'R' " everywhere with R.XXX.XXX

I've tried:

> 1.checking my xml files, including manifest
>
> 2.checking SDK whether Build Tools is installed
>
> 3.clean project
>
> 4.rebuild project
>
> 5.sync project with Gradle files
>
> 6.every way I could find on Internet

while rebuilding project the message shows "manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

I briefly paste a part of my activity here:

```
public class Clock_mainpage extends Activity {

private Button button_start;

private static final int START_LOCATION = 1;

private Item item;


private void findButton()
 {

    button_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

 }

 private Button.OnClickListener startclock = new Button.OnClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
   public void onClick(View view) 
    {
                Intent intentMap = new Intent(Clock_mainpage.this, MapsActivity.class);

                intentMap.putExtra("lat", item.getLatitude());
                intentMap.putExtra("lng",item.getLongitude());
                intentMap.putExtra("title",item.getTitle());
                intentMap.putExtra("datetime",item.getLocaleDatetime());

                startActivityForResult(intentMap, START_LOCATION);
                finish();

        }
    };
```

Seems it appears to be something wrong in my Manifest.xml
I post it below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hackntu.android.clock"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission      android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
<activity
    android:name=".Clock_mainpage"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Google Service edition -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Google Map API key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <!-- Map component -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />

        <activity/>

    <application/>

</manifest>
```

Well, this problem seems to be simple to every of you. But I wasted 3hours or more on it. Appreciate to all of you.
Sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't past the most important think in such problem with R a imports.
Problem is known and simple. For sure you had problem with some resources. R class was not generated. You get info from IDE that R can not be found and IDE propose you quick fix: import R class.

But because your R was not generated at that point and IDE has only android.R avaliable. IDE impot android.R

Please double check imports.
In import you should have:

```
yourpackage.R
```

Comment: I post " import com.hackntu.android.clock.R; " within imports
Seems problem still exit...."cannot resolve symbol 'R' "
Am I misunderstanding you @mariopce ? still thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case i have declared the same activity twice in the AndroidManifest.xml.
So it was giving me the duplicate merger error. Once i removed that my issue was resolved.
Make sure your activity is not listed twice in manifest.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the drawable ic_launcher was also being used by a dependency library. Looking at the gradle console in Android Studio helps in such situations.

```
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml
```

This solved my problem, your issue might be different but gradle console will certainly help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issues occurs because of manifest file. Delete newly added comments, empty tags like <intent-filter> </intent-filter> and rebuild your project. It should work.